# Open File In Silverlight 4 File operation not permitted

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight web application(4.0) with a select file open dialog, however I get this error when the user selects a file : "File operation not permitted Access to path '' is denied" 
When I try to debug it then I get this security exception "Dialogs must be user-initiated."
Is there a way around this? Has anyone has tried doing this in Silverlight?

Here is my code so far which hasn't worked:

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog
{
    Multiselect = false,
    Filter = "All files|*.*"
};
bool? userClickedOK = dlg.ShowDialog();

if (userClickedOK == true)
{
    textBox1.Text =  dlg.File.FullName;
}
```

Comment: Please use capital letters when possible, remove greetings and in general any time wasting character.

Comment: please refer http://aspnetbymeetu.blogspot.in/2009/09/file-handling-in-silverlight.html

Answer (score 2):

Because of security related restrictions you cannot open file dialogs in Silverlight directly. You can only open dialogs  from inside an event handler like mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

1. In silverlight 4, you cannot acces the **FullName** property, this is the cause of exception: "**File operation not permitted Access to path is denied**"
   I trien utmost but cannot find a way to get full file path of selected file without making your application **OOB**.
2. While debugging a silverlight project, if you place a break point anywhere before the **dlg.ShowDialog()**, in case of your code this will raise the exception: "**Dialogs must be user-initiated**"
   Simple way to avoid this exception is to place your break point after **ShowDialog()** line.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you are not allowed to access user files if you don't have elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the full name of a file. And in all cases, why would you need it? There is no reason to know where the user stores her files.

If you want to read a file, use `Stream` property of the uploaded file instead.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, after reading a lot about this problem that you cannot access

```
 dlg.File.FullName
```

Instead you can use this

```
 dlg.File.Name
```

by doing this your exception will be removed

Answer (score 0):

The error also occurs if you try to access CreationTime from a FileInfo.